# How to add multiple condition in PHP while looping

Tags: php, while-loop, do-while

I intend to stop this loop if one of this condition is true. But it is not working...

Is any one have the solution?

```
$x="sbplay1.com";
$y="";
$i=0;
$j=4;
$myUrl="No match found";
while(($y!=$x)||($i!=$j)){
    $node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item($i++);
    $myUrl = $node->getAttribute("href");
    $y= (parse_url($myUrl, PHP_URL_HOST));        
}   
echo $myUrl;
```

Comment: You can use `break;` together with an `if` statement. Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: It will execute everything in the `while` loop as long as the expression evaluates to `true`, could you clarify your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `if (($y!=$x)||($i!=$j)){ break; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the loop if one condition is true, then you need to negate the condition, like

```
while (!(($y!=$x)||($i!=$j))){
    $node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item($i++);
    $myUrl = $node->getAttribute("href");
    $y= (parse_url($myUrl, PHP_URL_HOST));        
}
```

If you want to stop the loop if exactly one condition is true, then you can check for inequality as well

```
while ((($y!=$x)||($i!=$j)) && (($y!=$x) !== ($i!=$j))){
    $node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item($i++);
    $myUrl = $node->getAttribute("href");
    $y= (parse_url($myUrl, PHP_URL_HOST));        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, hope will answer your question:
I see you want iterate the nodes from $i to $j, or until the host url is $x, then echo $myUrl;

```
$x="sbplay1.com";
$y="";
$i=0;
$j=4;
$myUrl="No match found";
for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item($i);
    $myUrl = $node->getAttribute("href");
    $y = parse_url($myUrl, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if ($x == $y) break;
}
echo $myUrl;
```